# Rails logging simply doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm trying to do easy logging

```
logger.error "ERROR!!!"
```

But nothing is displayed in any of the log files in the /log directory. I tried rescuing an exception, but there's no exception.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: where di you get this log ? In a controller/runner/rake/etc... ?

Comment: You have other output ?, request information ?

Comment: Are you just calling `logger.error` or `Rails.logger.error`?

Comment: Just logger.error. But I also tried Rails.logger.error - neither of them works. When I perform a migration, everything is logged ok.

Comment: Did you try RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.error ?

Comment: I tried all 3 ways on the server, and it worked! I don't know why it doesn't work on my Mac desktop...

Comment: have you checked your environment config to see if there's something in there that would cause your logging to be written to some other location than what you are expecting?

Answer (score 5):

Did you check that your production.log file has the proper rights? Try running `sudo chmod 0666` on your production.log file, that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

there might be a:

- permission problem. run "sudo chmod 0666" on the file. rails does show this when the server is started though
- rails uses a BufferedLogger. try a "logger.flush" Can configure it as well.

what does "logger.class" say? what logger are you using?
is the log file created? what is its permission and the permission for the log folder?
are you running the server on webrick (locally ?) or passenger etc?

eg. if you say "Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)" then the logs will go to stdout rather than  a file. check that as well

Answer (score 1):

Check output of `Rails.logger`. If it shows `RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x00007fe3b5bc3540` means you are logging on shell. Change it to  `ActiveSupport::Logger` by creating an initializer.

```
config/initializer/logger.rb 

Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('log/production.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to use `logger.debug` and `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.debug`.

However, the following works:

`Rails.logger.debug 'hello world'`

Then check the logs for the corresponding environment in your app's `/log` folder.